# Can I use information in 2 different columns to specify where to update information in UPDATE query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Consider this table:

```
Email | Message | Votes
------+---------+-------
Email1| Msg1    | 2
------+---------+-------
Email2| Msg2    | 1
------+---------+-------
Email3| Msg2    | 3
```

Now, I want to update the **3rd** cell under **Votes** column using following query:

```
UPDATE tablename SET Votes=4 WHERE Message=Msg2
```

But the problem is that it will update the both cells under **Votes**, where **Msg2** is present. But I want to update the cell where **Email=Email3** and **Message=Msg2**.

Can it be done using UPDATE query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple condtitions and join them with `AND`:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET Votes = 4 
WHERE Message = 'Msg2'
  AND Email   = 'Email3';
```

or using row-constructor:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET Votes = 4 
WHERE (Message, Email) = ('Msg2','Email3');
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68bda8/1/0)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

> I tried but it didn't work. It didn't update anything

So you have different data than you provided. Probably whitespaces. Try:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET Votes = 4 
WHERE TRIM(Message) = 'Msg2'
  AND TRIM(Email)   = 'Email3';
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. It didn't update anything.